# Multiple PHP Requisitions per minute

Tags: php, ajax, apache

Is there a way in the server-side to execute once an operation instead of execute it every time when I sent a PHP request?

For example, I have an website that makes a lot of requisitions, but its independent from user or anything else, it just depends on the application running in the server with wich I'm willing to manage with my website.

So I want a way to just get the data that I need, processed by a script in the server not by every PHP request, i.e. The server will execute the only once and then I can grab the data with PHP.

Comment: You should look into caching with PHP and Memcached

Comment: I'm really unclear about your question... but sounds like you want caching?

Comment: Or perhaps you are looking for a cron job ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lonut suggested use cronjob (linux) or task manager (windows) to run you PHP task at specific intervals.

You can run standalone php script from the command line by using `php path/to/your/script.php`